# Meteor Angular 2 - autobind not working in the tutorial

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor

I am following the Meteor - Angular2 tutorial and things work fine.

The only point not working is the automatic binding with Angular2 UI for the 'details view'. For instance, if I navigate to the details view of *Party1* the data of *Party1* is correctly loaded and made visible on the Angular2 'details view'. If, afterwards, the data of *Party1* is changed (e.g. via Mongo shell) such change is sent to the browser (via WebSockets) where 'details view' is displayed, but the new data is not shown on the view.

Here is the code of the `PartyDetailsComponent` class.

```
export class PartyDetailsComponent extends MeteorComponent implements OnInit, CanActivate {
  partyId: string;
  party: Party;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .map(params => params['partyId'])
    .subscribe(partyId => {
      this.partyId = partyId;
      this.subscribe('party', this.partyId, () => {
        this.party = Parties.findOne(this.partyId);
      }, true);
    });
  }

  saveParty() {
    Parties.update(this.party._id, {
      $set: {
        name: this.party.name,
        description: this.party.description,
        location: this.party.location
      }
    });
  }

  canActivate() {
    const party = Parties.findOne(this.partyId);
    console.log(party);
    return (party && party.owner == Meteor.userId());
  }

}
```

Here is the template of of PartyDetailsComponent

```
<form *ngIf="party" (submit)="saveParty()">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="party.name" name="name">
  <label>Description</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="party.description" name="description">
  <label>Location</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="party.location" name="location">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  <a [routerLink]="['/']">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What is not shown in the view? How do you bind it to the view?

Comment: I have updated the question with the template code. What is not shown is the new value. Let's assume that Party1 location is Monaco, when I load the details view the location is shown correctly. If then I change the location to Monza, then I see the new value of Monza to reach the browser (via WebSockets) but the view is not automatically refreshed and the location remains Monaco. Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to my questions just reading more of the Tutorial.

I can get automatic update ofthe UI once the underlying Mongo doc changes just adding Meteo autorun() method appropriately in the subscription code.

Here is the code that works

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .map(params => params['partyId'])
    .subscribe(partyId => {
      this.partyId = partyId;
      this.subscribe('party', this.partyId, () => {
        this.autorun(() => {
          this.party = Parties.findOne(this.partyId);
        }, true);
      }, true);
    });
  }
```

What is not totally clear to me is why if you use directly the Meteo Mongo cursors (e.g. via `*ngFor` in the template) autorun is not needed.